# What is FedEx API limits? How many times I can call the APIs?

Tags: wsdl, fedex

I have gone through documentation here provided http://www.fedex.com/us/developer/web-services/index.html but I am not able to find how many times I can query FedEx APIs

Does anyone have one idea or experience?

I don't want to put a bug in production code, so taking precautions.

[Documentation I follow](http://www.fedex.com/templates/components/apps/wpor/secure/downloads/pdf/201408/TrackServiceWSDLGuide_v2014.pdf)

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There are no hard API limits for web services. FedEx does audit logs so they will shut you down if you're sending too many requests, especially with tracking.

Comment: Thanks.  This boggles my mind that this is how they handle this, but you appear to be right.  It also seems like you can't do batch tracking requests and need to make them all individually, which also seems odd.

Comment: We've been asking FedEx for years to add webhooks or some alternative so that batch tracking becomes a thing of the past.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like they do have rate limits as of now (2022):
According to this [page](https://developer.fedex.com/api/en-jo/guides/best-practices.html)

> The throttling limit is set to 250 transaction over 10 seconds. If
> this limit is reached in the first few seconds, HTTP error code 429
> Too many requests will be returned and transactions will be restricted
> until 10 seconds is reached; transactions will then resume again. For
> example, if we receive 250 requests in the first four seconds, an HTTP
> error code 429 Too many requests - ‘We have received too many requests
> in a short duration. Please wait a while to try again.’ will be
> returned and transactions will be restricted for the next six seconds
> and then resume again.